# MySQL query based on 2 tables and a join table and rows should include all instances, in order, of joined data

Tags: php, sql, join, pivot

I need to create a table result (and find out if it IS possible within the constraints of MySQL) that will contain data from 2 tables, but the query itself will be based on 3 tables (including a join-table). And joined results should be added to the output results.

**Table Structures:**

```
registrants
id, first name, last name, industryID

industries
id, name

registrants_industries (join table)
id, registrant_id, industry_id
```

So in the final output results table, any registrant could have 0, 1 or many industries, and those industry names should be tacked onto the end of the final results table.

```
registrants.id, 
registrants.first_name, 
registrants.last_name, 
industry.name-1,      
industry.name-2,  
industry.name-3,  
industry.name-4,  
industry.name-5.
```

**But** all columns should align by industry. For example, if there were 5 industries, the output would be like so:

(**Industries are in this order:** 
Painting, Tiling, General Construction, Yard Care, Roofing)

```
354, Mike, Smith, Painting,’’,’’,Yard Care,’’
599, Joe, Jones, ‘’,’’,’General Construction’,’’,’’
```

So all industry columns would align and could be sorted in Excel etc.

**Is this query output with (My)SQL possible?** And if so, an you make any good suggestion on the best approach to this?

I began writing my query only to find no answers that solve my added columns based on matches. And getting it all together by row as I need.

Comment: And if there are 500 industries? If there are 50K industries? Excel can't handle 50K columns.

Comment: Do the industries have to be in multiple columns, or can they be grouped in one column, seperated by some character?

Comment: Interesting point. There are less than 350 industries.

Comment: They need to be in separate columns. Because of sorting and managing the data in excel.

Comment: I posted my answer anyway, for reference. I suggest you write a PHP script that will create a query with 350 joins ;) (I don't think mysql can even handle that many joins...)

Comment: @Pelshoff: You are right, there is a limit on 61 joins in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use group_concat and get all the industries in a single column. I'm aware that is not an exact answer to your questions, but it comes close and I don't believe what you ask is possible with only 3 joins.

```
SELECT
R.id, 
R.first_name, 
R.last_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(I.name) AS industries
FROM registrants R
JOIN registrants_industries RI ON R.id = RI.registrant_id
JOIN industires I ON RI.industry_id = I.id
GROUP BY R.id
```

This will produce

```
354, Mike, Smith, "Painting,Yard Care"
599, Joe, Jones, "’General Construction’"
```

Comment: Seeing that my plan is to output into csv format, this could work I think. I will need to run some tests.

Comment: If the separate columns is not an absolute requirement, this is definitely the way to go.  Note that you can sort the industries like `GROUP_CONCAT(I.name ORDER BY l.name)`

Comment: Pelshoff, I accepted your answer. I read about the GROUP_CONCAT() earlier today as a solution. I didn't like the comma setup, but in excel I can separate the cells based on the comma separator. I am working now on a php script that will do the comma seperation, so I can download direct to csv format... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a number to each `registrants_industries` entry using a subquery:

```
select  r.id, 
,       r.first_name
,       r.last_name
,       min(case when ri.RowNr = 1 then i.name end) as [Industry-1]
,       min(case when ri.RowNr = 2 then i.name end) as [Industry-2]
,       min(case when ri.RowNr = 3 then i.name end) as [Industry-3]
,       min(case when ri.RowNr = 4 then i.name end) as [Industry-4]
,       min(case when ri.RowNr = 5 then i.name end) as [Industry-5]
from    registrants r
join    (
        select  (
                select  count(*)
                from    registrants_industries ri3
                where   ri3.registrant = r2.registrant
                        and ri3.id <= ri2.id
                ) as RowNr
        ,       *
        from    registrants_industries ri2
        ) ri
on      ri.registrant_id = r.id
join    industries i
on      i.id = ri.industry_id
group by
        r.id
,       r.first_name
,       r.last_name
```

Comment: Andomar, Very nice query. It was a bit complex for my needs, but I will keep this for good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking to *pivot* values into respective columns.  This is a common requirement especially for reporting and exporting to spreadsheets.

In SQL, you need to declare the columns in the query, and they are fixed at query prepare time, before your query gets a chance to look at the data.  You can't have a query automatically add columns to its result set dynamically, based on the data values it finds.

The workaround is to *hard-code* expressions for each distinct value you will include in the query result:

```
SELECT r.id, r.first_name, r.last_name,
  MAX(CASE i.name WHEN 'Painting' THEN i.name END) AS `Painting`,
  MAX(CASE i.name WHEN 'Tiling' THEN i.name END) AS `Tiling`,
  MAX(CASE i.name WHEN 'General Construction' THEN i.name END) AS `General Construction`,
  MAX(CASE i.name WHEN 'Yard Care' THEN i.name END) AS `Yard Care`,
  MAX(CASE i.name WHEN 'Roofing' THEN i.name END) AS `Roofing`
FROM registrants r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  registrants_industries ri
  INNER JOIN industries i ON i.id = ri.industry_id
) ON r.id = ri.registrant_id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

This means you either need to know what distinct values possibly exist among your data, or else you need to discover it before you run the above query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM industries;
```

Then write application code to use that result to generate an SQL query string with a variable number of columns, one column expression corresponding to each distinct industry name.

The alternative is to not pivot using SQL, but instead fetch the raw data back to your application, and fetch multiple rows per user id, sorting results into an application data structure until you have some grid view that looks like the pivoted data set you want.

One way or the other you need to write application code, if you want a query that adapts to the data and returns a column for each data value that exists.  You either write code to pre-process data and generate an SQL query, or else you write code to post-process the data as you fetch it.

Comment: Bill, thanks for the detailed explanation. I've never had to write a query like this, but it really helps fills some gaps I could not find answers to.

Comment: For a challenge, I am going to write a php script for downloading the results as required into csv format. I've done this many times in the past, but never with a join-table like this. I'm planning to loop through an array of the industry names to output those MAX() functions - each with its respective industry name. I'm guessing there will be no conflicts, but won't know until I try it. Happy New Years!